# Find the maximum value of $|\arg (\frac{1}{1-z})|$ for $|z|=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\arg \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)$$
$$=\arg (1) - \arg (1-z)$$
$$=-\arg (1-z)$$
Placing the modulus gives
$$|\arg (1-z)|$$

Since it’s a circle, one point is $(1,0)$, then the point which is farthest away is $(-1,0)$, so the arg should be $\pi$. The correct answer is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. How is true?

I think I went wrong in using $\arg (1-z)$ when should be $\arg (z-1)$. I am not sure if that changes things, but that’s a possible flaw I noticed.

Comment: Note that you have to take $\arg(1-(-1))$ and not $\arg(-1)$ when talking about $(-1,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no maximum for the argument**:
Let $z=e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta,$ then $1-z=2\sin(\theta/2)(\sin(\theta/2)-i\cos(\theta/2))$ and hence $$\dfrac{1}{1-z}=\dfrac{1}{2\sin(\theta/2)}(\sin(\theta/2)+i\cos(\theta/2))=\dfrac{e^{\frac{i}2\left(\pi-\theta\right)}}{2\sin(\theta/2)}$$ for $\theta\neq 0.$ As you can see, argument change is $$\theta\mapsto \dfrac{\pi}2-\dfrac{\theta}2$$ for any $\theta\in(0,2\pi).$

If you want to see this more geometrically, observe that the image of the unit circle under the (Mobius) transformation $\dfrac{1}{1-z}$ is line $\Re(z)=\dfrac12$ on which there is no complex number with a maximum (or minimum) argument.

Comment: Here you are asking the wrong question. Since the other answers are still misleading, I have added more details to my answer.

Comment: I have seen a solution for this question (not on MSE), and it is indeed $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Pretty convincing

Comment: @Aditya: Well, then can you find a complex number on the unit circle which achieves $\pi/2$? However the "supremum" exist and it is exactly $\pi/2.$

Comment: I agree with @Bumblebee, there is no maxima, only supremum $\pi/2.$

Answer (score 2):

Denote the points $Z,O,I$ corresponding to the complex numbers $z,0,1,$ respectively.

$$\arg \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)=\arg \left(\frac{1-0}{1-z}\right)=\arg \left(\frac{0-1}{z-1}\right)$$ is the oriented angle between vectors $\vec{IZ}$ and $\vec{IO}.$
The angle gets larger when $Z$ approaches $I$ (on the unit circle) from "above" or, better said, clockwise. The value of the angle approaches $\pi/2,$ but this is never obtained.

Absolute value of the argument doesn't give more (see picture): approaching $I$ counterclockwise gives $$\left|\arg \left(\frac{0-1}{z-1}\right)\right|\to |-\pi/2|.$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

let $z=e^{ia}$

$1-z=2sin(a/2)e^{ia/2}$

thus

$arg(1-z)=a/2$

now by conventional domain $0\le a\le \pi$ and substituite...